# exclude rows with a particular ID if a joined value exists

Tags: mysql, sql, left-join

```
pollId  | user_id
   53   |  8
   53   |  3
   53   |  2
   61   |  null
   61   |  null
   62   |  1
```

If I am searching for the user_id of 8 my goal is to exclude all of the rows with the pollId 53 entirely.

If I use `and r.user_id != 8`, I still get a single unwanted row with pollId of 53. likewise if I use `and r.user_id = 8`. I just get the row with userId 8.

What I would want back is:

```
pollId  | user_id
   61   |  null
   62   |  1
```

The full query

```
      select p.poll_id, 
      r.user_id,
       from
      poll p
      inner join poll_question q 
      left join org_poll op
      on p.poll_id = op.poll_id 
      left join poll_result r
      on q.question_id = r.question_id
      where p.poll_id in (53, 61, 62) 
      and (op.org_id = 7 or p.all_orgs = 1) 
      and p.poll_id = q.poll_id
      and r.user_id != 8
      group by q.question_id
```

Comment: *exclude all of the rows with the pollId 53* - but assuming you don't mean `WHERE pollId <> 53`, do you actually mean "I want to exclude all pollId where any row in the pollId group has userid 8"?

Comment: Your intentions aren't 100% clear - should the same query return just user_id 8 *if* values 3 and 2 didn't share the same `pollId`?

Comment: It's probably easier to give it context. UserId signifies whether or not a user has taken the poll (53). I want to remove all of the rows from my query where user 8 has taken the poll, in this case 53. But I am getting additional rows from the other users who have taken the poll, 2 and 3.

Comment: `inner join poll_question q` lacks an ON clause. Does your MySQL operate with ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY off?

Answer (score 0):

If I get this right you want to exclude rows with `pollid`s that where ever associated with `user_id` 8. Then you can use `NOT EXISTS` and a correlated subquery.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
       *
       FROM poll p1
       WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                                FROM poll p2
                                WHERE p2.pollid = p1.pollid
                                      AND p2.user_id = 8);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a NOT IN to cover it in a fairly readable, logical way:

```
select p.poll_id, 
      r.user_id,
       from
      poll p
      inner join poll_question q 
      left join org_poll op
      on p.poll_id = op.poll_id 
      left join poll_result r
      on q.question_id = r.question_id
      where p.poll_id in (53, 61, 62)        
      and (op.org_id = 7 or p.all_orgs = 1) 
      and p.poll_id = q.poll_id
      and r.user_id != 8


AND p.poll_id NOT IN (
  SELECT q.poll_id 
  FROM poll_question q 
    JOIN org_poll op on q.poll_id = op.poll_id 
    JOIN poll_result r on q.question_id = r.question_id 
  WHERE r.user_id = 8)


      group by q.question_id
```

There are other ways too, such as doing a `COUNT(CASE WHEN user_id = 8 THEN 1 END) OVER(PARTITION BY poll_id)` in the SELECT and wrapping the whole thing in another select that demands the count be 0; needs MySQL 8

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from table T1
where
pollId not in
(
    select pollId from table T2 where T2.user_id=8
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not know your data model, but I think this query can help you. Like others responds I used `NOT IN` to get all rows of those poll_id that do not have a user_id = 8.

```
SELECT pq.poll_id, pr.user_id
FROM poll p
INNER JOIN poll_question pq ON p.poll_id = pq.poll_id
LEFT JOIN org_poll op ON p.poll_id = op.poll_id 
LEFT JOIN poll_result pr ON pq.question_id = pr.question_id

WHERE p.poll_id in (53, 61, 62) 
      AND (op.org_id = 7 OR p.all_orgs = 1)  
      AND p.poll_id NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT pq.poll_id
                            FROM poll_result pr
                            INNER JOIN poll_question pq ON pq.question_id = pr.question_id
                            WHERE pr.user_id = 8);
```